# React decrypt an encrypted string from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, encryption

I have an encrypted string created in NodeJS using `crypto`

NodeJS:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const key = Buffer.from(SECRET_KEY, 'base64');  

encrypt(text) {
   const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
   let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv( 
       'AES-128-CBC', key, iv);
   let encrypted = cipher.update(text);
   encrypted = Buffer.concat([iv, encrypted, cipher.final()]); 
   return encrypted.toString('hex');
}
```

It is working perfectly and I can't change the NodeJS. Then, I try to decrypt it using React `crypto-js`, but it returns an empty string.

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

const KEY = SECRET_KEY;

export const decrypt = (text) => {
    var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, KEY);
    return bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
}
```

Am I missing any configuration in React?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CryptoJS code is missing:

- Separation of IV and ciphertext.
- Specification of the IV.
- Suitable decoding for ciphertext, key and IV (using the corresponding CryptoJS encoder).

The following ciphertext was created with the NodeJS code:

```
d906539383bb4931c434d58daaf82dc95bc9d6833089a4fd0014b331060bc18fff2270b18c561cae36aebd48a82e9de5eaee31dc4ed059929fe37b9a468d9cdf
```

This can be decrypted with the CryptoJS code below:

```js
const KEY = 'MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NQ==';
function decrypt(text) {
    
    // Separate IV and ciphertext
    var iv = text.substring(0, 32);
    var ciphertext = text.substring(32);

    var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        {ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ciphertext)}, 
        CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(KEY), 
        {iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv)});  // pass IV
    
    return bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8); // or Hex as in the posted code 
}

var encryptedData = 'd906539383bb4931c434d58daaf82dc95bc9d6833089a4fd0014b331060bc18fff2270b18c561cae36aebd48a82e9de5eaee31dc4ed059929fe37b9a468d9cdf';
console.log(decrypt(encryptedData)); // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```